# Image tag's Background url property clipping the image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fetch an image from an url like below:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6Q5n/2/

```css
.img {
  background: url("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png") no-repeat;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  Facebook
</div>
```

I see that the image is clipped according to the given pixels whereas I want to fit **that entire image** within the above height and width (60*60px)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `background-size` to `100% 100%`, to make it fill the div both horizontally and vertically :

```css
.img {
     background:url("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png")   no-repeat;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
div {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  facebook
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the background size, not the size.

```
.img {
background:url("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png")   no-repeat;
        background-size: 60px 60px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Background size and position:

```
.img {
     background:url("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21-leKb-zsL._SL500_AA300_.png")   no-repeat;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Contain makes the image fit the element width and height but keep its aspect. position centers the bg on the element